# Initialize a constant for JUnit from a .properties file which gets itself initialized from the pom.xml file

Tags: java, properties, junit, initialization, constants

**Please forgive the intricate title**

**Background**

/pom.xml

```
...
<foo.bar>stackoverflow</foo.bar>
...
```

/src/main/resources/config.properties

```
...
foo.bar=${foo.bar}
...
```

Config.java

```
...

public final static String FOO_BAR;

static {
    try {
        InputStream stream = Config.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(stream);
        FOO_BAR = properties.getProperty("foo.bar");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

...
```

**Question**

In /src/main/java, I'm using `Config.FOO_BAR` in MyClass.java. If I want to test `MyClass` in a /src/test/java folder using JUnit with MyClassTest.java, how can I load the properties so that the `Config.FOO_BAR` constant get initialized?

I tried to add a hardly-written config.properties within /src/test/resources with `foo.bar=stackoverflow`, but it still can't get initialized.

Comment: Do you *have* to use a static initializer like that? Fundamentally you've written hard-to-test code... I'd urge you to avoid using statics so heavily.

Comment: @JonSkeet You mean I should better load the properties each time I need them rather than setting constants with their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it work by changing some in your `pom.xml` and your `Config.java`.

Add these lines to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

And change the order of some lines in `Config.java`:

```
public class Config {
    public final static String FOO_BAR;

    static {
        InputStream stream = Config.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(stream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // You will have to take some action here...
        }
        // What if properties was not loaded correctly... You will get null back
        FOO_BAR = properties.getProperty("foo.bar");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.format("FOO_BAR = %s", FOO_BAR);
    }
}
```

Output if running `Config`:

```
FOO_BAR = stackoverflow
```

**Disclaimer**

I am not sure what purpose you have with setting these static config values. I just made it work.

---

**Edit after comment**

Added a simple JUnit test to `src/test/java/`:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

/**
 * @author maba, 2012-09-25
 */
public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void testConfigValue() {
        assertEquals("stackoverflow", Config.FOO_BAR);
    }
}
```

No problems with this test.

Comment: Thanks, but that worked already. The problem now is to initialize the constants when running tests with JUnit, i.e. the *Test.java classes within the /src/test/java folder.

Comment: @sp00m Added a simple test case and it works fine. You must have some other issues that you haven't mentioned. My setup works well.

Comment: @sp00m BTW, what is it that worked already? The resource filtering or setting the `FOO_BAR`?