# Specifying a Maven profile when running JUnit tests within a Spring webapp

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, maven, junit

**Background**

/pom.xml

```xml
...
<properties>
    ...
    <jdbc.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbc.driver>
    <jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://${database.host}/${database.name}</jdbc.url>
    <jdbc.user>${database.user}</jdbc.user>
    <jdbc.password>${database.password}</jdbc.password>
    ...
</properties>
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            ...
            <database.name>database</database.name>
            <database.host>localhost</database.host>
            <database.user>root</database.user>
            <database.password></database.password>
            ...
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
...
```

/src/main/resources/database.properties

```
...
jdbc.driver=${jdbc.driver}
jdbc.url=${jdbc.url}
jdbc.user=${jdbc.user}
jdbc.password=${jdbc.password}
...
```

/src/main/resources/spring/applicationContext.xml

```xml
<beans ... xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" ...>
    ...
    <bean
        id="dataSource"
        ...
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.user}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}"
        ... />
    ...
</beans>
```

/src/**test**/java/com/company/project/service/MyItemServiceImplTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring/applicationContext.xml" })
public class MyItemServiceImplTest {

    @Resource
    private MyItemService myItemService;

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        MyItem myItem = new MyItem();
        myItemService.save(myItem);
        ...
    }

}
```

**Question**

When running the tests, it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'database.password'
...
```

I guess it's because I need to run the tests while specifying the `dev` profile like I do when I launch the webapp (using `-P dev`). But I can't make it work. Is it even possible?

**PS**

The filtered applicationContext.xml file (i.e. the one in /target/classes/spring/applicationContext.xml) is identical to the one in /src/*, but the filtered database.properties file (i.e. /target/classes/database.properties) looks like

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://${database.host}/${database.name}
jdbc.user=${database.user}
jdbc.password=${database.password}
```

It means that from the pom.xml file to the .properties one, the properties have been well filtered, but within the pom.xml itself, the properties that depend on the chosen profile won't get filtered. Probably because I want to specify anywhere the profile I need when launching the tests. But as I said before, `-P dev` doesn't seem work with JUnit...

Comment: What does you `applicationContext.xml` file look like after it has been filtered?

Comment: @maba How should I process to get the filtered one?

Comment: If you followed my last [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579712/initialize-a-constant-for-junit-from-a-properties-file-which-get-itself-initial/12580154#12580154) I showed you how to filter resources. If you build with `mvn compile` you will have passed the [`process-resources`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) phase and in your `target/classes/` folder you will have the filtered resources.

Comment: @maba See my edit. Thank you for helping. I haven't answered you yet in the last question I posted because I think the problem comes from these Maven profiles which need to be activated.

Comment: @maba I made it working. In fact, I'm using [eCobertura](http://ecobertura.johoop.de/) to launch the tests, and that generates the errors I posted. I just tried with `mvn -Pdev test` and it does work, because I could specify the profile. Is there any way to launch this working Maven command from eCobertura?

Comment: I have never used eCobertura so I have no clue.

Comment: @maba Alright, many thanks though, I'll keep searching around eCobertura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource filtering is performed in the [`process-resources`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) phase. So if you state `mvn test -Pdev` you will have passed that phase and all filtering has been done. It doesn't matter to JUnit what profile you are running since you are not doing anything else differently in that `dev` profile.